# Ruby: Extracting Words From String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, parsing

I'm trying to parse words out of a string and put them into an array. I've tried the following thing:

```
@string1 = "oriented design, decomposition, encapsulation, and testing. Uses "
puts @string1.scan(/\s([^\,\.\s]*)/)
```

It seems to do the trick, but it's a bit shaky (I should include more special characters for example). Is there a better way to do so in ruby?

Optional: I have a cs course description. I intend to extract all the words out of it and place them in a string array, remove the most common word in the English language from the array produced, and then use the rest of the words as tags that users can use to search for cs courses.

Comment: The English language is difficult to parse with regular expressions. Have you considered a natural language parser? It will more accurately recognise the difference between the periods in the sentence `Mr. Smith is here.` and return `Mr.` as a single word including the dot, but `here` without the dot.

Comment: @MarkByers, very good point, I did not at this point. I will look into it. Thank You!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The split command.

```
   words = @string1.split(/\W+/)
```

will split the string into an array based on a regular expression.  \W means any "non-word" character and the "+" means to combine multiple delimiters.

Comment: Is there something this direct in Python? Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't always work.  "Café Restaurant".split(/\W+/) => ["Caf", "Restaurant"] drops the special character.

Comment: There is also a problem with numbers: `"8.3".split(/\W+/) => [8.3]`

Comment: Beware of spaces at the beginning of the string: `"  aa bb".split /\W+/  => ["", "aa", "bb"]`

Comment: Simply use `strip` to remove spaces first, so: `@string.strip.split(/\W+/)`

Comment: This doesn't work for words with contractions like "you're" and "it's"

Comment: The answer below by @lazzy.developer also works with multilingual words, special characters and punctuation as seen in this example: http://rubular.com/r/8ZfgmWP1Au

Answer (score 22):

For me the best to spliting sentences is:

```
line.split(/[^[[:word:]]]+/)
```

Even with multilingual words and punctuation marks work perfectly:

```
line = 'English words, Polski Żurek!!! crème fraîche...'
line.split(/[^[[:word:]]]+/)
=> ["English", "words", "Polski", "Żurek", "crème", "fraîche"]
```

Comment: Thanks. Works well for non-latin words.

Comment: What about contractions?

Comment: ["can", "t"] handle contractions

Comment: Contractions are not handled. You can try `line.split(/[^[[:word:]]']+/)` but all `'words'` still be `'words'`

Answer (score 14):

Well, you could split the string on spaces if that's your delimiter of interest

```
@string1.split(' ')
```

Or split on word boundaries

```
\W  # Any non-word character

\b  # Any word boundary character
```

Or on non-words

```
\s  # Any whitespace character
```

Hint:  try testing each of these on http://rubular.com

And note that ruby 1.9 has some differences from 1.8

Comment: As noted in david nehme's answer, you might want yo use the + operator to indicate one or more successive characters that match that pattern

Comment: Also, scan is great for pulling matching patterns out of a text and would work with the reverse of our split suggestions above e.g. s.scan(/w+/)

Comment: thank you for the many great suggestion! I played a lot with rubular this morning and it's an amazing teaching tool. I was just having trouble implementing extraction of the selected pattern into my code.  @string1.split(%r{\W+}) seems to work well but Mark Byers (commenter above) has a good point about natural language parsing, so I'll need to keep it in mind. In any case, THANK YOU!

Comment: Note BF4 is missing a backslash in his/her comment, should be: `s.scan(/\w+/)`

Answer (score 1):

For Rails you can use something like this:

```
@string1.split(/\s/).delete_if(&:blank?)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write something like this:

```rb
@string
  .split(/,+|\s+/)  # any ',' or any whitespace characters(space, tab, newline)
  .reject(&:empty?)
  .map { |w| w.gsub(/\W+$|^\W+^*/, '') } # \W+$ => any trailing punctuation; ^\W+^* => any leading punctuation
```

```
irb(main):047:0> @string1 = "oriented design, 'with', !!qwe,  and testing. can't rubyisgood#)(*#%)(*, and,rails,is,good"
=> "oriented design, 'with', !!qwe,  and testing. can't rubyisgood#)(*#%)(*, and,rails,is,good"
irb(main):048:0> @string1.split(/,+|\s+/).reject(&:empty?).map { |w| w.gsub(/\W+$|^\W+^*/, '')}
=> ["oriented", "design", "with", "qwe", "and", "testing", "can't", "rubyisgood", "and", "rails", "is", "good"]
```