# Regex to match three letters and delete three letters

Tags: ruby, regex

I've been trying to figure out a regex to output only three letters and also to delete the word "not"

What I've tried so far is:

- `.gsub(/^[A-z]+$/)` (still outputs the same as below)
- I also tried everything on [this post about Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617797/regex-to-match-only-letters)

Here's what I need regexed:

```
bash: line 1: drs: command not found
bash: line 2: tep: command not found
bash: line 3: ldo: command not found
bash: line 4: tep: command not found
bash: line 5: txw: command not found
bash: line 6: tep: command not found
bash: line 7: jfp: command not found
bash: line 8: mys: command not found
bash: line 9: jhf: command not found
bash: line 10: mjw: command not found
bash: line 11: czw: command not found
bash: line 12: txh: command not found
bash: line 13: krn: command not found
bash: line 14: sct: command not found
bash: line 15: jad: command not found
```

I want it to only output:

```
drs
tep
ldo
tep
txw
tep
jfp
mys
jhf
mjw
czw
txh
krn
sct
jad
```

Is there a way I can do this? Please keep in mind I have multiple other three letter combinations, with all letters of the alphabet.

Comment: are the letters always in that place? I mean, is always "bash: line xxxx: ABC: ...."?

Comment: @zon7 Yes they are always in the same place, I'll edit the post hang on..

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Is there working code? Is there sample input and your expected output?

Comment: *WHY* do you want to delete the word "not"? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: **Warning: Dot not use `[A-z]` in regexes.**  It matches uppercase and lowercase ASCII letters as you expect, but it also matches several punctuation characters whose code points lie between `z` and `A`.  Use `[A-Za-z]` instead, or make use of the case-insensitive flag (e.g., `/[a-z]/i`).

Comment: @AlanMoore I had no idea it matched punctuation characters, thanks for the information!

Comment: You could improve your question in several ways: 1. State what you want to do without reference to the approach that you think should be taken (e.g., use of a regex). 2. When you give an example, ensure each input value is a valid Ruby object. Here it's not clear if your text is a string or an array of strings. You should write `"bash: line 1:...."` or `["bash: line 1:...]`. 3. Assign a variable to each object that is an input for your example (e.g., `str = "bash: line 1:...."`) so that readers can refer to the variable in comments and answers without having to define it. (cont.)

Comment: ...4. Ensure the example illustrates each element of the question. Here you say that you want to "delete the word 'not'", but that word does not appear in your example. 5. Make the example as brief as possible to make the point. Here 3-5 lines would have been enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why regex? You are overcomplicating your life:

```
def three_letters_excluding_not(text)
    text
      .split(/\W+/)
      .select{|w| w.length == 3}
      .reject{|w| w=="not"}
end
```

Short, easy, readable, enjoy the power of Ruby.

Comment: What's the `w` for..?

Comment: @Bam More info at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622369/ruby-extracting-words-from-string `\W` means _non-word_

Comment: `w` is a block variable.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem like a good use of regex since you're dealing with fields:

```
str = "bash: line 14: krn: command not found"
str.split(': ')[2] # => "krn"
```

Here's a more thorough test:

```
[
  'bash: line 1: drs: command not found',
  'bash: line 2: tep: command not found',
  'bash: line 3: ldo: command not found',
  'bash: line 4: tep: command not found',
  'bash: line 5: txw: command not found',
  'bash: line 6: tep: command not found',
  'bash: line 7: jfp: command not found',
  'bash: line 8: mys: command not found',
  'bash: line 9: jhf: command not found',
  'bash: line 10: mjw: command not found',
  'bash: line 11: czw: command not found',
  'bash: line 12: txh: command not found',
  'bash: line 13: krn: command not found',
  'bash: line 14: sct: command not found',
  'bash: line 15: jad: command not found',
].each do |str|
  puts str.split(': ')[2]
end
# >> drs
# >> tep
# >> ldo
# >> tep
# >> txw
# >> tep
# >> jfp
# >> mys
# >> jhf
# >> mjw
# >> czw
# >> txh
# >> krn
# >> sct
# >> jad
```

If you don't know how many spaces will surround `:` delimiters, use `strip` to remove leading and trailing whitespace from the word captured:

```
str.split(':')[2].strip
```

Comment: Oh what I meant is that the `[2]` searches through two whitespaces?

Comment: @Bam, split returns an array,[2] is index into the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
str =<<_
bash: line 1: drs: command not found
bash: line 2: tep: command not found
bash: line 3: not: command not found
bash: line 4: tep: command not found
bash: line 5: txw: command not found
_

r = /
    \d:\s+ # match a digit, colon and one or more spaces
    \K     # forget everything matched so far
    .{3}   # match any three characters
    /x     # extended/free-spacing regex definition mode

str.scan r
  #=> ["drs", "tep", "not", "tep", "txw"]
```

If you don't want "not":

```
str.scan(r) - ["not"]
  #=> ["drs", "tep", "tep", "txw"]
```

If this is not a one-off calculation, consider whether the text format may change in future. If it might, implement a method that you think is least likely to require modification after the change.

Answer (score -1):

This should do:

"bash: line.*?: (.*?):"

This will get everything from bash till the ": " after line and return in a group the three or more letters before the ":"

You can test it here
http://rubular.com/

Comment: I don't want to return `three or more letters` only three,

Comment: It should only return three, but it's prepared to return more. It just works :)